# Parse filter list for FileDialog

Tags: c#, .net

If I have a filter string like this (filter for FileDialog):

```
"Image Files (*.bmp, *.jpg)|*.bmp;*.jpg|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
```

Is there a function in C# that gives me a list of all extensions in this filter?

This would be

```
"*.bmp", "*.jpg" and "*.*"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with this regular expresion:

```
(?<Name>[^|]*)\|(?<Extension>[^|]*)\|?
```

Here is a sample code:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<Name>[^|]*)\|(?<Extension>[^|]*)\|?");
var matches = regex.Matches(@"Image Files (*.bmp, *.jpg)|*.bmp;*.jpg|All Files (*.*)|*.*");
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Debug.Print("Name: '{0}' Extension:'{1}'", match.Groups["Name"].Value, match.Groups["Extension"].Value);
}
```

Comment: All answers are excellent, but I choose this one, because I have some more requirements, which I can resolve very easy with this version too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. However, it's easy enough to write one yourself.

```
public string[] getExtensions(string input) {
    if (string.isNullOrEmpty(input) || input.indexOf('|') == -1) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        List<string> returnValue = new List<string>();
        string[] parts = input.Split('|')
        for(int x = 1; x < input.Length; x+=2) {
            foreach(string extension in parts[x].Split(',')) {
                returnValue.Add(extension);
            }
        }
        return returnValue.ToArray();
    }
}
```